# HTML5 Css3 Grid Layout Not Working Even When I Copy an Example from w3.org

Tags: css, grid-layout

Would appreciate any help trying to get css3/html grid layout to work. I have tried the below code in IE, chrome, and Edge, and can't get it to work. Maybe there is something I have overlooked.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}
#title {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
#score {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}
#stats {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  align-self: start;
}
#board {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
#controls {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="title">Game Title</div>
  <div id="score">Score</div>
  <div id="stats">Stats</div>
  <div id="board">Board</div>
  <div id="controls">Controls</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

The Grid implementation(s) [are not widely (or hardly at all) available in any browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) as of July 5, 2016.

You can enable it in:

- Firefox; with the setting - `layout.css.grid.enabled`
- Webkit **nightly**; with the prefix - `-webkit-`
- IE/Edge; with the prefix - `-ms-`
- Chrome; with the `experimental Web Platform features` flag in `chrome://flags`

Note that the Firefox/Chrome options only enable this *for you*, and there's no way to force a user to enable these settings, so this would be for experimentation purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Between #grid and #title, include

```
#grid>div {    
   background:black;
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px 0;
   font-size:30px;
   color:white;
}  
    (any properties you choose)
```

I added a background and grid-gap under #grid also.